# How can I display a grid of data using WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

To learn WPF, I am trying to create a hex editor application. However, I am unsure of what I should use to display the hex dump to the user.

I am trying to display an array of integers in 16 columns. The first byte would be in column 1, row 1, the second byte in column 2, row 1, and so on.

I had considered using an array of TextBlock, but that seems inelegant. A DataGrid doesn't really look right for the way I am trying to display the data either.

What is the way to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you would like to display your data, but I suggest to use a listView. DataGrids are basically made from a listView. You can define the ItemTempplate any way you want it to appear, so I would think that somehow, you'll get the look and feel you're looking for.